# Why am i getting this exception error ? ArrayOutOfBounds?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I'm trying to check if the integers in an array are increasing. But I'm getting ArrayOutOfBounds exception, and I do not understand why. I'm new to programming.

```java
for (int i =0; i > newArray.length ; i++){
    if (newArray[i] > newArray[i+1]){
        System.out.println("Not increasing");
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The loop condition should be `i < newArray.length`, but actually the loop should not even be executing for a non zero sized array.

Comment: the stop condition shd be i < newArray.length. Additionally, newArray[i+1] is accessed, so in fact it shd be i < newArray.length-1.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yeah thanks i copied the wrong code from my IDE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the ArrayOutOfBounds exception happens when you are trying to access a non-existent position in the array.

The problem in your case is the `newArray[i+1]` which tries to access a position non-existent in your array.
I recommend editing the condition `i < newArray.length-1` : There are, of course, other ways to fix this but this is the easiest.

Comment: i understand the exception but i did not think of this, thank you, it works now

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say your array length is 8 so the positions are from 0 to 7 
In the last run of the for loop i=7 and i+1 =8 
You don’t have newArray[i+1]
You should put the first if inside a new if

```
if(i<(newArray.length - 1)){
if (newArray[i] > newArray[i+1]){
System.out.println("Not increasing");
}
}
```